# Why doesn't std::transform convert the std::string vector to unsigned int vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++14

As described in the title, I am trying to convert a vector of `std::string` to `unsigned int`. But I am getting a segmentation fault. Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>

int main() {
    unsigned int N = 3;
    std::string array_string = "2 5 8";
    std::vector<unsigned int> A;

    std::istringstream array_stream(array_string);

    std::vector<std::string> array {
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{array_stream},
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}
    };
    A.clear(); A.reserve(N);
    std::transform(array.begin(), array.end(), A.begin(), [] (const std::string& str) {
        return std::stoi(str);
    });
    for(std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator it = A.begin(); it != A.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << A.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

OTOH, changing `A.begin()` to `std::back_inserter(A)` in the call to `std::transform` works. Is this because `A.begin()` fails when `A` is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this because `A.begin()` fails when `A` is empty?

Yes, that's why. Your call to `reserve` doesn't change the fact that `A` is empty, it is still empty afterwards. Calling `reserve` only changes the *capacity*, i.e. subsequent insertions will not allocate any memory.

If you want to use `A.begin()`, you have to call `resize`, as that will actually change the size of `A`:

```
A.resize(N); //Resize array
std::transform(array.begin(), array.end(), A.begin(), [] (const std::string& str) {
    return std::stoi(str);
});
```

Comment: What happens to `A` after `resize` is called?

Comment: @Priyatham After `resize` `A` has: `capacity >= N` and `size == N`. The new elements are default constructed

Comment: So, in this case they are zeros? Thanks!

Comment: Another alternative: Don't do any `resize`, and `std::transform(array.begin(), array.end(), std::back_inserter(A), []...)`

Comment: Oops, yeah, missed that.